# Automatically Resize Partitions to Bare Minimum Needed to Store Files

Tags: command-line, partitioning, bash, ext4

I am currently writing a bash script in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS that automatically backs up devices that are running ubuntu-server 18.04 LTS. I don't think this is version-specific, so I didn't tag it that way. In order to not have to spend hours doing manual backups through command line, I was hoping to have a script that backs up devices automatically. The only thing that I have left (I think) is resizing the image file so that there is no "blank" space being taken up.

Normally, you can setup the loop for the image file so you can access the partitions, resize the partition with `gparted`, then `truncate` the image file. This, however, takes time when you have lots of devices being backed up and I would prefer to do this automatically.

The portion of code that I have for shrinking the `.img` file is intended to setup a loop from the `.img` file that came from `dd` run on a remote machine, then access the main ext4 partition, resize it to the bare minimum needed to store the files that are already on it, and `truncate` the partition so that the size is the same as the partition. After the whole process is complete, I would remove the loop and repeat the process for all the other `.img` files. The only thing that I need to accomplish in theory (Haven't tested this part yet) at the moment is the commands for shrinking the partition. I think I have figured out how to do everything else, including truncating.

I have researched this extensively over the past couple days, and all I  found was methods through the command line that require you to visually see the amount of space used, resize the partition to that size, then `truncate`. This method of visually seeing the used space, etc. won't work with a bash script as configured in all the articles that I have researched. [This](https://softwarebakery.com/shrinking-images-on-linux) article shows what I'm trying to achieve very well, just through gparted instead of automatically in a bash script. As mentioned at the start, I need this to be compatible with Ubuntu 18.04-20.04 LTS at a ***MINIMUM***. If I have missed something obvious, please let me know.

Comment: I don't need someone to audit the script. I have verified functionality of the partially finished script that has everything needed to do an automatic backup except shrinking the ```.img``` file. I just would like to know what I can do to achieve what I have outlined in the question.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/Lc9csxwX) is the unfinished script that I have been working on. It contains the code that is needed to get the image file from the two machines and then compress them to a directory. [This](https://pastebin.com/b3WDERd1) second script that I am trying to finish contains the code that will shrink the image file. I want to shrink it because I don't need or want to be storing all 32 GBs of a drive when I'm only using 5 of them. This will also leave room for more than one backup on my drive. I have achieved shrinking through ```loop``` and ```gparted``` manually.

Comment: I only have a desktop & use rsync, and only copy my data and some settings.But those that run servers suggest rdiff. https://rdiff-backup.net/
Discussion of issues on rsync bash file &  rdiff-backup  - TheFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2440020 Sample rdiff file by TheFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436006
Summary report from rdiff & use variables, example
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2422831 & 
http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/examples.html

Comment: Great idea, but rdiff and rsync don't make bootable copies, while dd does. I have looked into this, and rsync was my original choice for my script, until I found out that it doesn't make a bootable copy. Sure, it backs up your data, but you will have to do some setup all over again. With dd, just flash and you're right back to where you're started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `resize2fs`, which despite its name operates also on ext4 filesystems. The option `-M` reduces the filesystem to its minimal size. You can then use `parted` and its command `resizepart` to resize the partition to fit.

`tune2fs -l` on the filesystem will print out its current size in blocks, and the size of a block, to calculate the new partition size for `parted`.

```
Block count:              5242800
Block size:               4096
```

Comment: Use `tune2fs -l` to get the size of the filesystem. `parted` uses units of sectors (512bytes) by default I believe.

Comment: great. Any way to do this automatically without needing visual clues? I would like mundane tasks to be fully automated as mentioned above. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing visual or GUI in the above. A shell script can extract the values from tune2fs and calculate the number to put in a parted script. If that is what you need help doing you should post a question for each step with a concrete small example of what you have, what you tried and what you need.

Comment: Ok. I'll try this and get back to you. The thing that I'm unsure about is the script differentiating between the letters and the two number values.

Comment: All worked as expected. I overcame the differentiation issue with sed like so: ```command | sed -n 's/.*<text to search>//p'```. Marked as accepted answer.